# jQuery/JavaScript: Push item to least full 'row' in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay, so i've got a multi dimensional array of coordinates.

```
var coords = [],
    rows = 3;

coords[0] = [{x:35,y:35}...];
coords[1] = [{x:35,y:35}...];
coords[2] = [{x:35,y:35}...];

// Assume each row has a different number of entries in.
```

Essentially, i want to be able to push to whichever 'row' in the array has the least in it.
So if **coords[0].length** is *greater* than **coords[2].length**, push to *coords[2]*.

I know i could loop through, but i'm looking for the most efficient way of doing it, or writing a little function to do it.

Cheers.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as adding elements in increasing order? i.e. add first to `coords[0]`, next to `coords[1]`, next to `coords[2]`. Lather, rinse and repeat

Comment: Ahh, i forgot to mention each row would already vary in length. Amended my question.

Comment: You have also forgotten to mention if they are going to be externally modified or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about my solution

```
var coords = [],
    rows = 3, 
    whereToPush = 0;

coords[0] = [];
coords[1] = [];
coords[2] = [];

function push(a){
    coords[whereToPush].push(a);
    whereToPush += 1;
    if(whereToPush >= rows) whereToPush = 0;
}
```